# Localhost service accessible from remote address

Tags: proxy, netcat

I have on my home Windows box - Cassini server with localhost:10000. And I want it be accessible in internet by my static IP.

Tried netcat, "nc -l -p 10001 localhost 10000". But it results in "invalid connection to [IP] from  [IP] 16074"

Also before that it was working on Opera Unite properly, but now only writes a message: "An error occured. See error log for details". I dont know where to get that log.

Answer (score 1):

> `nc -l -p 10001 localhost 10000`

Every machine in the world thinks that ***it*** is named "localhost". That command won't work when you're not on the machine running the server on port 10000.

To access it from other LAN machines you need to replace `localhost` with the server's internal IP address. To access it from outside your LAN (outside the firewall) you'll need to configure your firewall with a rule for that port to forward it to the internal server IP. Then you'll access it by replacing `localhost` with the firewall's external IP address.